# Elimination of the node

Tags: astronomy, solar-system, models

Recently I have been reading a lot of astronomy papers on reductions in models of the solar system. A reoccurring concept is the elimination of the node. However, they never explain what the node is and why the reduction removes it. Could anybody explain this to me or otherwise refer me to some nice literature.

Comment: Deprit's original paper is available at http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1983CeMec..30..181D